# Get header value in react js app sent to a web-view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, header

I am working on a application where admin panel is built with ReactJs and app is built with react native, both are working fine except the authtentication on a admin page which needs to be opened in webview from react native app.

This app is a customer management system and each customer has a qr code, android app scans qr code and opens a url for that customer in webview, to open webview I am using following code which works fine

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <WebView
    bounces={false}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    ref={webView => (this.webView = webView)}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    domStorageEnabled={true}
    allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
    source={{
      uri: webUrl,
      headers: {
        "x-auth-token": UserSession.getToken()
      },
      method: "GET"
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Above code opens the admin panel but with login page, I tried to collect passed token in react app send it as api request header to authenticate but there is no way to collect the header without xmlhttprequest.

Is there a way to get the token value from header and use it ?

Comment: did u find a way?

Comment: I did it with a url containing one time auth token which validated the current user

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, any luck?

Comment: any solution?...I also stuck